# Setting up an Apple Profile Service for iOS Over-The-Air-Profile Delivery

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, mdm

What we are trying to do, is to setup a Profile Service for Over-The-Air Profile Delivery for iOS.
We are following the steps specified in Apples Document (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html)

We have setup our server as specified in the docs, with the specified handlers for "/enroll", "/profile", etc.
The step we are currently stuck at is step 3 of the Certificate Enrollment phase (Phase 2). Our Profile service is receiving the "GetCACert" request, but the installation of the profile subsequently fails, with the message "Invalid response from the Registration Authority."

When we look at the provided sample ruby code, from the same above site, the handler for "/scep" basically returns the root_certificate, and the ra_certificate. However, we can't find much information regarding the RA_Cert: What is it used for, and how is it generated?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In the example script, the ra_cert is used as the certificate authority actually issuing the certificates for the devices.

It is loaded the init-function from the ra_cert/ra_private.pem files. If they don't exist yet, the certificate and key is created and signed with the root certificate (which is itself generated on the first launch of the script).

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for your input.
Actually, after going through both the Apple Over-The-Air Configuration document mentioned above, as well as the IETF SCEP standard, it started to make more sense. While the sample script itself does generate the "RA_Cert" if its not available, it isn't required, depending on the services setup.According to the SCEP standard, the Registration Authority "is an SCEP server that performs validation and authorization checks of the SCEP requester but forwards the certification requests to the CA"

Answer (score 0):

The RA certificate (technically, two certs/key-pairs, one for signing, one for crypting, but they will usually be the same) is needed when you yourself are not the CA that issues the returned certificate, but are acting on behalf of it.

If you are the CA, you sign and encipher the SCEP response with the CA cert. If you are an RA acting on behalf of a CA (you don't have access to the CA's private key), you sign and encipher using you RA keys.

Note that even if you have access to the CA's private key, using an RA is recommended from a security standpoint, as it minimizes the operations your CA's private key is used for, and hence exposes it less.

Lastly, note that in the GetCACert call, if you are in RA-mode, the recommended order in which to return the certificates is the RA cert(s) (sign and cipher) first, then the CA. At least that was the recommandation from Apple some time ago when I had trouble with the same stuff.